# How to fix "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'" when updating data -Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have created small kind of application in code igniter, in this application I am currently creating a  forgot password module.
I have created a function but don't know why it's not working; I need random, auto-generated password to send out in an email, but when i click submit button it say's Array to string conversion error, so give me some suggestion.

Here's my view

```php
<?php

$attributes = array('class' => 'user', 'method' => 'post' );

echo form_open('Authentication/forget_password',$attributes);

?>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" type="submit">Reset Password</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller

```php
public function forget_password(){
    $email =$this->input->post('email');
    $result = $this->Authentication_model->check_email($email);

    if($result){

        $this->sendpassword($result);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Password has been reset and has been sent to your email :'.$email);
        redirect('Authentication/view_forgot');

    }else{

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','The email you entered was not found on our database');
        redirect('Authentication/view_forgot');
    }
}

public function sendpassword($result){
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $password= random_string('alnum', 16);
    $this->db->where('email', $result);
    $this->db->update('users', $password);
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('cantreply@youdomain.com', 'Your name');
    $this->email->to($user->email);
    $this->email->subject('Password reset');
    $this->email->message('You have requested the new password, Here is you new password:'. $password);
    $this->email->send();
}
```

And My Model

```php
function check_email($email){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query ->num_rows()==1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify how the email method "does not work," and/or where you are getting the "Array to string conversion" error (ie, include the full error). My suspicion is that the array is being returned by your `random_string` function - please include this as well so we can check that.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I already edit the message, thanks

Comment: Please include the `random_string` function code as well.

Comment: Where is your SQL statement with the `where clause`? Please include that as well.

Comment: I already stated it in my function "public function sendpassword($result)"

Comment: that's calling the function, for anyone to help we need to see the code behind the likely problematic code. Additionally, seeing the query, please provide the output of `$query`, though I expect it just says "Array" instead of real data because of `random_string`.